# Generate random "pattern-lock" sequence of digits

Tags: php, math, random

Today my friend raised a challenge that I still can't solve: "Generate a random digit sequence in PHP"

The digits are arranged as dial-pad/pattern-lock that consist 1-9 keys in 3 rows and 3 columns:

```
 ---------------------------
|                           |
|     1       2      3      |
|                           |
|     4       5      6      |
|                           |
|     7       8      9      |
|                           |
 ---------------------------
```

Now, given a length, we have to generate a random, non-repeating sequence of digits of the provided length, using these criteria:

1. A generated sequence should follow a specific direction/pattern going only via neighboring digits (possibly diagonally), for example (length:8), 12569874:

   ```
    1  2
         
    4    5  6
            
    7  8  9
   ```
2. Digits from the first row should never be followed by a digit from the third row, and vice-versa. The same goes for columns. For example a 1 cannot be followed by a 8, and a 6 cannot be followed by a 4.
3. can guess more criteria can easily from android pattern-lock system

Here are some example generated sequences for length 9: 12369874/5, 142536987, etc, and for length = 6: 987532, etc

I tried to do this with `rand()`:

```
  $chars = "123456789";
  $length = 9;
  $clen   = strlen( $chars )-1;
  $id  = '';

  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
      $id .= $chars[mt_rand(0,$clen)];
  }
  return ($id);
```

but, still no luck...

How can I solve this question?

Comment: Can you explain your criteria better?

Comment: Sounds like you have the criteria in mind, and should then first attempt it in longhand, bruteforce approach. Get the result you are looking for by any means (and however many loops and if blocks lol). You should be able to do it. Just keep looping over the criteria until all rules match up.

Comment: @Manav: thanks 4 the reply, please check the updated question

Comment: @Randall: i think looping is not the solution...

Comment: Depends. You have so many criteria, that its not really a random number. Each number you try to 'randomly' pick, has to undergo a checks and balances (mini function), in a while loop until it meets a true result. Then the third number, and so forth. It can be a long bit of code... but it would also be quite the brain stretcher :)

Comment: Another way would be... to make up a huge table of every possible number that is allowed to follow every possible number. Then make a random pick, then using the result, randomly pick from the lookup table of allowed values. And repeat 8 more times.

Comment: @Randall: :) thanks for your valuable suggestions... currently i'm working the table :)

Comment: From the examples it seems that (1) there cannot be repetitions in the sequence, (2) the path should not be crossed (e.g. 1 5 2 4 should not be allowed because 2->4 crosses 1->5). What about 1 8? Is that allowed? What about 1 9? So... what are the other rules you have not listed?

Comment: @trincot: crossing is allowed to next or previous row only, 1 -> 5 -> 2 -> 4 is valid, but 1|2|3 -> 7|8|9  OR 9|8|7 -> 1|2|3 is not allowed because the cross the middle row

Comment: And 4 -> 3, crossing the middle column? Is that allowed?

Comment: @trincot: 4 -> 3 is not valid, bcoz its crossing the column

Comment: OK, I have added my answer, because I see the answer you accepted does not stick to the rules you provided here. Your question is a bit misleading as the example you give for rule 1 is not allowed by rule 2, since it has the 9-8-7 sequence in it. But I have applied that rule also in my answer.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood rule two? Does it mean that if you have 1-2, that it cannot be followed by 3, and if you have 7-8 it cannot be followed by 9? That is how I understood it, but maybe this is about something else?

Comment: @trincot: rule:2 mentioned that, IT SHOULD FOLLOW A SPECIFIC SEQUENCE that can't go back, means, if 8 is followed by 9, than 9 cannot follow 7 (8->9->7 is wrong or 4->1->7 is also wrong or 6->9->3 is also wrong)

Comment: Ah, so put in other words, you must visit neighboring digits only (including digonally). Then I overcomplicated my answer. Please see the second, more simpler implementation I added to my answer. If that is a correct understanding I will remove the first part of my answer.

Comment: I have removed the first part of my answer. Now the code is even more straightforward. I have also edited your question to (hopefully) better describe the rules. Please check if this is OK for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

has some limitations but that's for you to work out.  I only deal with headaches when I get paid :).

```
<pre>
<?php

// Keypad
$grid = [
    ['1', '2', '3'],
    ['4', '5', '6'],
    ['7', '8', '9'],
];

// Sequence Target Length
$target_length = 5;

// Place to store the Keypad sequence
$points = [];

// Starting Point
$x = rand(0, 2);
$y = rand(0, 2);

// Run through the process until we have the sequence at the desired length
while (count($points) < $target_length):

    // Check if the grid keypad entry has been used
    if ($grid[$x][$y]):
        // Hasn't been used, so stire it
        $points[] = $grid[$x][$y]; 
        // Mark it used 
        $grid[$x][$y] = NULL;
    endif;

    // Sanity Check, imagine if you will,.... target length of 9, and you hit 6 5 2 1,  You'll vault off into the twilight zone without this
    if ((!$grid[$x + 1][$y]) && (!$grid[$x][$y + 1]) && (!$grid[$x - 1][$y]) && (!$grid[$x][$y - 1])):
        // We have no where to go
        break;
    endif;

    // Start looking for possible values 
    do {
        $test_x = $x;
        $test_y = $y;
        $dir = rand(0, 3);

        switch ($dir):
            case (0):
                $test_y--; // Up
                break;
            case (1):
                $test_x++; // Right
                break;
            case (2):
                $test_y++; // Down
                break;
            case (3):
                $test_x--; // Left
                break;
        endswitch;
        // Optional Gibberish 
        echo "Moving from {$x}, {$y} to {$test_x}, {$test_y} --> " . (($grid[$test_x][$test_y] === NULL) ? 'FAILED' : 'OK!') . '<br>';

        // Keep going until we find a valid direction
    } while ($grid[$test_x][$test_y] === NULL);

    // assign the new coords
    $x = $test_x;
    $y = $test_y;

    // repeat
endwhile;

// report
echo implode('-', $points) . "\n";

?>
</pre>
```

Comment: man u r just awesome... thanks a lot & dear u r a PRICELESS person :) so I can't afford to pay u ;)

Comment: Happy to help! (Just kidding about the paid part, I code for fun :) )

Comment: This seems to allow to generate 1-2-3, and never produces other moves then vertical or horizontal neighbors. Also, with target_length = 9, the results are often incomplete.

Comment: Show me where the OP mentioned moving diagonal and I'll adjust it.  target_length = 9 is effectively "run as long as you can".  It's a small grid and a proof of concept,  the details are for the OP to address.  Personally if I had need for it I'd go with a base 36 grid (6x6 0-9A-Z) and also start from the center (as much as possible).  But again, not what he asked for.

Comment: @trincot: yup, sometimes Wranorn solution didn't produce the valid output based on exact length but its always works like a charm.

Comment: @trincot I upvoted your solution, it is more thorough.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that will apply these rules:

- a path can only step to neighboring cells, i.e. that are adjacent, including diagonally
- a path cannot contain the same cell twice

The following algorithm uses recursion for every digit that is added to the sequence. Whenever the sequence gets "stuck", backtracking happens, and an alternative path is tried. Backtracking continues if no more alternatives are available.

It is guaranteed that a path of the given length is returned, provided the given length is between 1 and 9:

```
function randomSequence($len) {
    if ($len < 1 || $len > 9) return []; // No results
    $row = [null, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3];
    $col = [null, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];
    $neighbors = [[], [2, 4, 5],       [1, 4, 5, 6, 3],          [2, 5, 6],
                      [1, 2, 5, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 3, 5, 8, 9],
                      [4, 5, 8],       [4, 5, 6, 7, 9],          [5, 6, 8]];
    // Shuffle the neighbor lists to implement the randomness:
    foreach ($neighbors as &$nodes) shuffle($nodes);

    $recurse = function ($seq) use (&$len, &$row, &$col, &$neighbors, &$recurse) {
        if (count($seq) >= $len) return $seq; // found solution
        $last = end($seq);
        echo "try " . json_encode(array_keys($seq)) . "\n";
        foreach ($neighbors[$last] as $next) {
            if (isset($seq[$next])) continue; // Skip if digit already used
            $result = $recurse($seq + [$next => $next]);
            if (is_array($result)) return $result;
        }
    };
    $choice = rand(1, 9);
    return array_keys($recurse([$choice => $choice]));
}

echo "result: " . json_encode(randomSequence(9)) . "\n";
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/IjxB/14)

Comment: Corrected now, and I added another link, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in pseudocode for a matrix that looks like this:

```
1 2
3 4

# Get which other numbers are "legal moves" from each number.
adjacency = {
    1: [2, 3],
    2: [1, 4],
    3: [1, 4],
    4: [2, 3]
}

# Get the length of code required.
n = 8
# Start at a random position;
pos = rand(keys(adjacency))
result = []
while (n > 0)
    n -= 1
    newpos = rand(adjacency[pos])
    result[] = newpos
    pos = newpos
print(result.join(', '))
```

If your matrix is going to be large or is going to vary you might want to write some code to generate `adjaceny` rather than hardcoding it.